Slow Virtual Machine Performance on Ubuntu Server with VirtualBox
I am running two virtual machines on an Ubuntu 24.04 server, but they perform significantly slower compared to when I host them on Windows Server with an identical setup. Both VMs are accessed via Remote Desktop Connection (RDP), and there are substantial lags and display refresh delays not present when using the same configuration on Windows. The host server has ample resources, and the hardware utilization remains low, but the VMs’ responsiveness is still an issue.
Host Server Configuration:
•   OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
•   CPU: Intel Xeon (two CPUs)
•   RAM: 32GB DDR4-2133 ECC/Reg
•   HDD: RAID 1 (4x 4TB SATA drives)
•   Virtualization Software: VirtualBox with Guest Additions installed

Remote Desktop Setup:
1.  RDP Server: Installed and configured using xrdp for Ubuntu, allowing both root and non-root users to connect.
2.  Access: Both VMs are accessible via Microsoft Remote Desktop on macOS and Windows, which is configured to connect to the xrdp server on Ubuntu.
3.  Configuration Steps:
•   Installed xrdp and enabled it to start automatically.
•   Added the necessary users (e.g., root and user) to allow RDP access.
•   Configured the xrdp service to support multiple sessions simultaneously, allowing each user to connect independently.

Virtual Machine 1 (campfire):
•   OS: Ubuntu 22.04 (64-bit)
•   Memory: 16GB
•   CPU: 2 cores
•   Disk: Located on /mnt/VirtualMachines/user/campfire/campfire-disk001.vdi (SATA)
•   Graphics: VMSVGA with 32MB VRAM, 3D Acceleration disabled
•   Network: NAT (NAT network with an 82540EM adapter)
•   Other Features: Nested Paging, VT-x VPID, Unrestricted Execution, large pages enabled
•   Shared Folders: /mnt/Work_Download/camping, /mnt/VirtualMachines/shared

Virtual Machine 2 (campfire2):
•   OS: Ubuntu 24.04 (64-bit)
•   Memory: 12GB
•   CPU: 2 cores
•   Disk: Located on /mnt/VirtualMachines/user/campfire2/campfire2.vdi (SATA)
•   Graphics: VMSVGA with 16MB VRAM, 3D Acceleration disabled
•   Network: NAT (NAT network with an 82540EM adapter)
•   Audio: Enabled (AC97)
•   Other Features: Nested Paging, VT-x VPID, Unrestricted Execution, large pages enabled

Observed Issues
1.  Performance Lag: Display updates and input lag occur when accessing the VMs through RDP on Ubuntu. The same setup on a Windows host performs smoothly.
2.  Slow Refresh: Screen refresh rates seem delayed, which is noticeable in applications requiring frequent display updates.

Questions
1.  Could the performance differences stem from limitations or configurations within the VirtualBox setup on Ubuntu compared to Windows?
2.  Are there specific RDP configurations or window management optimizations on Ubuntu to reduce the display latency?
3.  Would using alternative remote desktop tools improve the responsiveness for Ubuntu-based hosts?

